# Flat File Analysis Normalization

Tags: excel, ms-access, data-analysis, database-normalization

I have a single table containing data on home efficiency projects. It includes project data, measure data (e.g. air conditioner, insulation), and measure attribute data (e.g. quantity, brand name, model number). Each row in the table is an individual measure attribute, which means all less discrete data (projects and measures) are repeated in multiple rows.
I need to analyze the data to answer questions like: what's the most common measure? What's the average cost of a measure?

When I use an Excel 2010 Pivot Table, I can't analyze by unique projects and measures because single projects/measures are split into multiple rows, when I sum in the pivot table it double/triple counts (or more, depending on the number of measure attributes).

My question: in order to analyze by projects and measures, do I need to normalize the table and import into a database like Access? Or am I not being creative enough in how I am arranging the pivot table?